# Bullet points in unordered list moving all the way to the left on mobile

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to go through the basics of web development on MDN, and for some reason, the bullet points in my unordered list are getting moved all the way to the left of the body.  I tried adding a padding of 0 to unordered lists, but that didn't help.

Here it is on a desktop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ljiR.jpg

Here it is on mobile:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvSPK.jpg

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li>Movies</li>
    <li>Television</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Books</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: gainsboro; /* silver/gainsboro/lightgray ? */
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    border: 5px groove black;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #5A4568; /* dark purple from google */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

h2 {
    color: darkred;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
}

p, ul {
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #B70404; /* dark red from google */
}

a {
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #5A4568;
}

.coming-soon-subscript {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #2D7F32;
    font-weight: normal; /* these elements will be appearing in headers, which are automatically bolded.  this is to remove the bold-ness. */
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

hr {
    margin: 0 -20px 20px -20px;
}

button {
    text-transform: none;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set `display: inline-block` to `<ul>`, then set `text-align: left` to `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display: inline-block` to `ul` in the css - but it will only bring the bullets closer to the list with all bullets left aligned while the text is centered. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQxVNJ

A workaround for this is to remove the default bullets of the `ul` using `list-style: none` in css and use unicode `&#9679` in the HTML as the bullets. Like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tm794sq2/1/